# Trying to gain admin privileges on windows 10 without an admin login

Tags: windows-10

I have a PC with no admin login available so I'm trying to replace `utilman.exe` with `cmd.exe` using the command prompt available when booting from a Windows 10 usb.

However when trying to replace the file I'm getting the error:

> the system cannot find the path specified

This line is confusing my command prompt.

```
copy c:\windows\system32\utilman.exe c:\
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you change boot order (i.e. booting from USB) on the PC you need Admin privilege?

Comment: Check your COPY command.

Comment: Are you sure boot disk is mounted on c:\ when booting from USB? Also, that command will not replace anything, just copy utilman.exe to root of c: if utilman.exe exists on that path. And c:\ exists as mounted drive.

Comment: Yes I can change boot order, im currently booting.from USB. I dont know that the usb is mounted on c, but Im not trying to move files on the boot USB, im trying to move files on the hard drive. At least I.think thats the intention. If Im booting the system from the USB, is that assigning a different letter to the hard drive? I know that commands only moving the file but its the first step to replace it and thats failing to find the correct path so im trying to get that working first. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: My USB was assigned c:\ and my hard drive reassigned to e:\ when booting from the USB. All working perfectly now!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was just a typo in the filepath.